# How does Spring Config Server Fetch Values from Git using Queues

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

I am doing a course from Udemy, and implemented Spring Cloud Config Server, with Git as Backend. Every thing seems to be working fine.

I have following Spring Cloud Config Server: [ConfigServer-RI](https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/SpringBoot-Microservices-Reference-Implementation/tree/master/ConfigServer-RI)

In ConfigServer-RI I have following entry in `application.properties` file, for configuring rabbit mq.

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/ConfigServer-RI
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh

spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

I also have User Microservice: [User-RI](https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/SpringBoot-Microservices-Reference-Implementation/tree/master/Users-RI)

In User-RI, I have following entry in `application.properties`

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

Now if i make change in `applicaiton.properties` in Git file, https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/ConfigServer-RI, and then call, the Spring Config Server, with following  URL http://localhost:8012/actuator/bus-refresh, the changes that are done in the Git properties file are reflected in User-RI Microservice i.e. the changes from Git repository properties file are accessible to User-RI Microservice without restarting it.

**Question**: I am not able to understand, how the data is flowing from Git Repository to Microservices, when I configure the queue details in `application.properties` file.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bus

Comment: I went through the above link, but it does not clarify how and where the microservices are registered with the queues. Does it mean that just by updating pom.xml and application.properties registers the application with queues. Also I have not made use of @RefreshScope.
Thanks.

Comment: "t just by updating pom.xml and application.properties" exactly